# Cannot use [chunkhash] or [contenthash] for chunk in '[name].[chunkhash].js' (use [hash] instead)

Tags: webpack

I'm getting this error when trying to run `webpack build` with hashing in my config:

```
ERROR in chunk main [entry]
[name].[chunkhash].js
Cannot use [chunkhash] or [contenthash] for chunk in '[name].[chunkhash].js' 
(use [hash] instead)
```

Webpack dev server runs fine

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Odd, I'm getting the reverse. Dev server errors, build works fine. Also solved for me by removing `--hot`, but that's not really a solution :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Commented out `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` in the plugins helped fix this

Comment: How is that a solution if you need the HotModuleReplacementPlugin?

Comment: You can have different configurations depending on environment. You probably don't need hash in filename at the same time that you need `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`.

Answer (score 22):

My solution was to change the filename depending on whether the mode is production or development:

`filename: mode === 'production' ? '[name].[chunkhash].js' : '[name].[hash].js',`

Fixed my problem and still able to use chunkhash for my production filenames as well as HotModuleReplacementPlugin.

Comment: Where do you change this?

Comment: It was in the output section of my webpack.config.js file.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me too...thanks to @pizzaae. One thing to note, is that you  [never want to enable HMR during production](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hot-module-replacement-plugin/). Having different Webpack configs for Prod and Dev can help if you want to use both HotModuleReplacementPlugin and chunkash.

Comment: +1. Very useful because I forgot to remove `--hmr` when trying a production mode build on local development server (`ng serve --prod --hmr`).

Answer (score 6):

I did something more like this, so you don't have comment out functionality

```
output: {
    filename: process.env.production ? `bundle-[chunkHash].js` : `bundle-[hash].js`
}
```

ChunkHash should only be used in production.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to enable the Hot Module replacement for a dev server, so I changed it to this:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

if config webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() on mode: 'development'. removed or commented out
webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() form plugins.

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map', // source-map
  devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      //hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
      new ManifestPlugin({fileName: '006.manifest.json'}),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
      //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
})
```